# How do I remove "References" from my running header?

Tags: biblatex, fancyhdr

I am using fancyhdr to create a short running title for an article I'm drafting. I also need my tables and figures to be printed after the bibliography upon submission to the journal. Initially, the running title works how I want it to by printing in the top right portion of the page. However, after I use the command to print the bibliography, the running title is altered and includes "References" on the top left portion of the page, as well as the header that I actually want. After the bibliography, subsequent pages continue to include "References" in the running title. How do I remove "References" from the running title? (I don't want "References" to appear in the running title for any pages).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames = 2,mincitenames = 1,maxbibnames = 99,minbibnames = 1,dashed = false,firstinits=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}  
% !BIB TS-program = biber     
%^ line above is necessary to tell TeXShop to use Biblatex rathern than traditional BibTex.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % utf8 support       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % code for pdf file  % w/out these two lines, I get the warning, "WARN - The entry '_______' has characters which cannot be encoded in 'ascii'. Recoding problematic characters into macros.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Test.bib}    
@unpublished{usgs_gmted_data,
Author = {{United States Geological Survey}},
Title = {USGS Global Multi-resolution Terrain Elevation Data (GMTED) product},
Url = {http://topotools.cr.usgs.gov/gmted_viewer/},
urldate = {2013-09-01}, 
urlmonth = {September},                                                    
Year = {2010}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{Test.bib}


\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}    % No line under running header
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead[R]{my running header}


\begin{document}
abc
\newpage
\nocite{*}
\newpage
abc
\printbibliography
\newpage
abc
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under your settings, the bibliography is printed as a `\section`, which naturally updates the header content using `\markboth`. You can set `\markboth` to gobble its arguments temporarily, which would therefore not affect the header:

```
{\renewcommand{\markboth}[2]{}% Remove header adjustment
\printbibliography}
```

Here is your minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames = 2,mincitenames = 1,maxbibnames = 99,minbibnames = 1,dashed = false,firstinits=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}  
% !BIB TS-program = biber     
%^ line above is necessary to tell TeXShop to use Biblatex rathern than traditional BibTex.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % utf8 support       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % code for pdf file  % w/out these two lines, I get the warning, "WARN - The entry '_______' has characters which cannot be encoded in 'ascii'. Recoding problematic characters into macros.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Test.bib}    
@unpublished{usgs_gmted_data,
Author = {{United States Geological Survey}},
Title = {USGS Global Multi-resolution Terrain Elevation Data (GMTED) product},
Url = {http://topotools.cr.usgs.gov/gmted_viewer/},
urldate = {2013-09-01}, 
urlmonth = {September},                                                    
Year = {2010}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{Test.bib}

\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}    % No line under running header
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead[R]{my running header}

\begin{document}
abc
\newpage
\nocite{*}
\newpage
abc
{\renewcommand{\markboth}[2]{}% Remove header adjustment
\printbibliography}
\newpage
abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did this, and after Texstudio asked to change something about my command \printbibliography command the file stopped compiling. The line `!BIB TS-program = biber` was messing everything up.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to work around this problem is to simply define the header for either the entire document or just the pages of interest as an empty header. Here is a MWE of how I did this:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{}
```

I simply placed these lines in the preamble and successfully removed the reference headers.